# Re-authenticate and delete user with email link

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm struggling with problem with re-authentication user with firebase email link. 
I cannot delete user account.

The process looks like bellow:

1. User creates an account by adding email address
2. Link is successfully sent on email
3. Universal link works
4. Authentication by clicking on link works
5. User account is created on Firebase
6. Saving this link on `UserDefaults` works
7. Deleting account when re-authenticate user does not work...

It throws an error:

[image]

This is the code for delete user account:

```
func deleteAccount() {

    // Create progres HUD
    let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
    hud.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Deleting Account", comment: "")
    hud.show(in: self.view)

    // #1 Create firebase credential to re-authenticate user
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else {return}
    let link = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Link")
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, link: link!)

    // #2 Re-authenticate user
    currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in

    // #3 if there is no error, remove user from database
    if error == nil {
        currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
        guard let userID = currentUser?.uid else {return }
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("User").child(userID).removeValue()

        if error == nil{
            hud.dismiss()
            self.delegate?.deletePinAnnotation(email: email)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    } else {  // #4 If error when re-authenticate user occurs 
         print(error.debugDescription)         
    }                        
    hud.dismiss()                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I should not use the same link that I used when creating the account. During reauthentication I should send another link.

using the same method:

```
Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: email, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { (error) in
      // ...
      if let error = error {
      self.createAlert(withDescription: error.localizedDescription)
      print(error)
      return
     }
   // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
   // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
   // if they open the link on the same device.
      UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "Email")
      self.createAlert(withDescription: "Open email to check the link")
   // ...
  }
```